# asp.net core starts up ok, but all Http requests fail to run

Tags: entity-framework, routes, asp.net-core, razorengine

Recently I started a new Asp.Net core application 1.0, and copied some existing code across from another project. After adding a considerable amount of code, and getting it to compile, I found that starting the application, appeared to start up, but when it tried to hit the Home controller to get the start page of the application, the browser reported it could NOT reach the web page. Reported a **This site can’t be reached** message (as if the web application was not running). This was very frustrating as the app used to work fine before I added all this extra code.

I ended up having to go back and start a brand new application (in the same project), and add components back into the project one at a time, till i found the thing that had caused this issue. A frustrating day passed where I could not get any errors from the server at all regarding why it failed to find the web page.

After a lot of menial work and cursing, I eventually tracked down the issue.

The issue was that I had added some support to do the database seeding as part of the Configure method of the Startup class. I had made this a Async Static Method, and called the method using an await inside the Configure method. Naturally I had to make the configure method Async which I did. 
The reasons for adding these awaits, were so I could use Async calls within my DatabaseSeed method call

```
public class Startup
{
   ...
   public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       ...
       using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
       {
           serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
           await DbExtensions.EnsureSeedData(app.ApplicationServices);
       }
       ...
   }
}


public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static async Task EnsureSeedData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var auditService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AuditService>();
            ....
        }
        ...
   }
```

**WARNING: DO NOT use the code above as an example of what to do.**

So this all compiled fine and the application started up as per normal. But like i stated above, No Http calls would find the web application

So I found out that due to the await call in the configure method (which was also marked as async now), this caused the application to be in a ghost state, and not responding to any routing calls.

My question to anyone that can answer, is why the routed calls didn't register anywhere as an issue, when it failed to access the Web application?
Note I couldn't even get a debug breakpoint to be hit in any controller code.

Comment: do not mark Configure as `async void`. The caller (WebHostBuilder) can't wait for the method to run, so you end up without a configured application.